# Smart Stack vs ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am interested in service discovery. I am looking into using Smart Stack. One of the tenants in the synapse repo for using smart stack ( https://github.com/airbnb/synapse ) says that the AWS ELB only supports external requests, but this seems to say otherwise http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/vpc-loadbalancer-types.html  Am I missing something? Why would I use Smart Stack over a private ELB if this is not true?